# How can I configure ProxyPass in the case of both directory path only and with file path

Tags: apache, proxypass

What I want is a redirect configuration like the following.

```
https://example.com/abc => https://test.com
https://example.com/abc/test.html => https://test.com/abc/test.html
```

I am trying to do that but not working yet.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/abc/$ https://test.com
ProxyPass /abc https://test.com/abc
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you most likely need (notice the slashes):

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/abc$ https://test.com
ProxyPass /abc/ https://test.com/abc/
```

To cover the use case you're explaining.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.